# How can you suggest the addition of a new package?

Tags: package-management, motu

[This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+bug/638654) has had a solution proposed in [comment 4](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+bug/638654/comments/4) which involves the addition of a new package to the system. How would I bring this to the attention of the developers?

Comment: you could try AU chat...there are some people there starting PPAs >.>

Comment: @jokerdino - Correct. Now should I delete the question like the other time or only close it and do a redirect for people that might find this question easier than looking for the original one.

Comment: Don't delete the question. Let's just close it as a dupe. :)

Comment: Voted as dupe. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/NewPackages) has information on how to request a new package.

> To get a package into Ubuntu, please [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug?no-redirect&field.tag=needs-packaging) in Launchpad and make sure it has the tag needs-packaging. Please mention where to get the source for it and which license it is under. An example request is [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/NewPackages/ExamplePackageRequest). Make sure you check which packages have [already been requested](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bugs?field.tag=needs-packaging).

Comment: Sorry for revisiting such an old question, but is that the same process for requesting the inclusion of new packages on the CD, or is that something different?

Comment: I think it's different for that, might be worth asking that as a a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to first file a RFP (Request For Packaging) bug in Debian against wnpp (Work-Needing and Prospective Packages) :

> Work-Needing and Prospective Packages, WNPP for short, is a list of
>   packages in need of new maintainers and prospective packages in
>   Debian. In order to closely track the real status of such things, WNPP
>   is currently operated as a pseudo-package in the Debian Bug Tracking
>   System (BTS).

Once the package is bought in to Debian sid, you will need to sync it from Debian into the Ubuntu repositories. This can be done by using the `requestsync` tool :
`requestsync -d sid --lp <packagename> precise` (where precise can be replaced by a Ubuntu Distro which is yet to be released)

Comment: I have to say that is a very good answer. Can you add some links to where I can check for more info about this and learn from there please. Thank you.