# Where could one go to suggest new packages for Ubuntu

Tags: package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you suggest the addition of a new package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22536/how-can-you-suggest-the-addition-of-a-new-package)

Sometimes one finds a package that looks very good and can help in some ways, but the package is not found in the repositories of Ubuntu or in any PPA site. Apart from creating a PPA, how and where can one suggest a package to be included to Ubuntu in a future or present version.

Some quick examples might be:

Komodo (Another alternative to Notepad++): http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/01/komodo-edit-the-best-notepad-alternative-in-ubuntu/

mkahawa (Cafe Management System): http://sourceforge.net/projects/mkahawa/

And many others that can help in making users use Ubuntu more.